# 0402 SMD resistance shortcut

Tags: led, surface-mount

I am wiring a small plastic model with 11 yellow 3V 0402 LEDs. I used the resistance calculator to find I need as many 56ohm resisters attached to each LED in parallel to keep them running properly, but that takes up an awful lot of space in a very thin model.

Is there any way I can keep them powered safely but not need to wire 11 resisters? The website won't show me any other way and I'm not the best at researching this stuff.

Thanks[image]

Comment: `attached to each LED in parallel` ...are you sure?

Comment: what website are you talking about? .... you may need eleven resistors or you may need less or you may need only one .... it is impossible to guess given the near zero information that you provided ...... what is the actual problem with doing research?

Comment: Manny, can you connect the LEDs in series (each series string will require a single series resistor)?  Do you have (or can you create) a voltage supply high enough to connect multiple LEDs in series?

Comment: http://led.linear1.org/led.wiz

Comment: Sorry Jsotola, I thought details I gave were enough to go by.

Comment: Thanks Tom that is pretty similar, and quite solidly answers my question, though I still wonder if I could get away with one resister if I'm using 10 identical LEDs... As opposed to different ones.

Comment: @MannyMcArthur  You will not get away by virtue of having identical LEDs (even if they are from the same batch).  One LED will become slightly warmer than the rest, and it will pull more current.